# Natural Language Parser that can handle syntactic and lexical errors

Tags: reference-request, natural-language-processing

I have some background in natural language processing and I know that all parsers (top down or bottom up, or mix), at least when I studied just about a few years ago, cannot handle any error. A small error like a grammatical one or a spelling one will result in unexpected parsed tree.

This is unacceptable in natural language in most cases. Thus I have been trying to find a way to make a new one with a different approach.

The basic general abstract idea is that I will use a top down dynamic programming approach.
Given a string of text with $n$ tokens, several top down fillers will be generated. These fillers will look at the tokens to see if they can find and fill constituents that they are missing. Because of this, these fillers might leave gap after they have found everything they need. This is supposed to make the parser more robust.

An example will be best to illustrate this idea:

Given the sentence: `I saw the ordinary thing`.

One top down filler can be. $S \rightarrow Subj - Verb - Object$.
This filler will try to look for span that it can use to fill its expectation of seeing a $Subject$ followed by $Verb$ and $Object$. This means it will deployed three other fillers in sequence. The first one is $Subj$. This filler will scan and add to the cache three possible subjects which are $I$, $saw$, $thing$. $I$ is put in span $[1,1]$, $Saw$ in span $[2,2]$, $thing$ in span $[5,5]$. This will result in a total of three potential pending parse trees. Then with each of these pending parse tree, $Verb$ filler is deployed to scan the span after each possible subject. $Object$ filler is deployed to scan the rest.

With the above approach, sentences such as `I .. eh... saw the big thing`
or similar constructs do not cause problem because fillers look for what they need and fill them into the tree. This problem is dealt with when all fillers have completed. Fillers that leave lot of gaps (unused tokens) will not generate parses having high score compared to parses generated by fillers that use up all tokens.

This is also my approach to deal with subject-verb agreement and male-female as well as singular-plural agreement. You deal with them at the ranking stage so that you can give your parser much better error tolerance. Sentences such as `Maybee they ehh can get something` can still be parsed. One resulting parse will just not use `Maybee`. The top parses will then be used again, this time to look for unused tokens. Unused tokens will be processed with spelling correction, did-you-mean style. One can see how it works with incorrect sentences like `This is a valide argument`. Even incorrect sentences like `They did got it` are still parsed ok.

There will be other fillers which cannot find all they need such as conditional sentence filler. $CondS \rightarrow "If" - S - ["then"] - S$. Some filler such as imperative $ImpS \rightarrow ["Please"] - Verb - Object$ will complete most of the times because it can find all it needs abeit leaving gaps, but then it is a ranking problem to make sure that the correct one is returned.

**So my Question** is:

- Has anyone ever thought of this approach? Any reference papers?
- If nobody used it before what may be the potential problem?

Comment: What you describe seems rather ad hoc. Is there any formalization of
it so that it could be formally compared to other approaches. Formally
compared does not necessarily mean theoretical comparison, but at
least some formal references and definitions so that even experimental
comparison can make sense. As it is I cannot be sure I understand
enough to do it as you would do it. So I have no reference. But there
are other techniques based on formal grammars that can achieve similar
effects. Is there a reason for dismissing them? What is your potential
problem with them? It may be a reverse answer

Comment: @babou I agree, this does not seem rigorous enough. I will try to edit with an example to make this even more formal and rigorous. It will be followed shortly by the code. PS: I don't have any problem at all with formal grammar. In fact this is based on formal grammar, each filler is really just a context free grammar rule in essence.

Comment: You seem to hail from the rule-based community (Grammatical Framework?). Are you familiar with statistical approaches to translation at all?  The whole ngram business (used by Google, afaik), for instance. (That said, it seems to me that enriching a rule set by commmon mistakes is conceptually easy, if a pesky task.)

Comment: @Raphael I am not familiar with statistical approach to translation, but I am aware of ngram business. I try to find a more balance approach with both statistics (on the ranking part) and the rule/model (on the parsing part). It is supposed to make the parser better with better use of both.

Comment: @InstructedA I see. I attended a workshop on these things back in 2010; back then such a hybrid approach had not been attempted (iirc) and was hence subject to future research. I have not followed the community since, though. Note that there is [linguistics.SE]; if no answer is forthcoming here after a week or so, you can (re)ask there.

Comment: I am still missing something formal enough to get my teeth in.  Why
should this work better than standard chart parsing, with weighted
editing rule to account for grammaticality problems, and weight based
selection of best parses.

Comment: @babou Ah ha, that's exactly what I was looking for, from what I have been taught about standard chart parsing, I haven't seen any weighted editing rule at all. All I have seen do not allow gaps. I will look into what you tell me. About weight based selection of best parses, I haven't seen any re-ranking (or general ranking for that matter) that would help avoid using large amount of annotated data.

Comment: @InstructedA I cannot answer right now, no time. The basic idea is that the techniques used in speech processing to build word lattices have a counterpart in context-free languages (and other types of grammars, such as TAGs) for handling ungrammatical input. It is actually quite simple. The weights can be produced by statistical analysis, though that is more difficult an I am no expert on it. See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33145#33185 for a simpler problem.  Be back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already know about dynamic programming parsing, aka chart
parsing. This is usually defined for Context-Free grammars (CFG), but
can be extended to other grammatical formalisms, where it can make
more or less sense, depending on the structural complexity of these
algorithms. There are various papers describing chart parsing for
specific formalisms, particularly in the computational linguistic
literature. One general view of the underlying structure common to all
these algorithms is described in a [1995 paper by Lang](https://www.academia.edu/798690/Recognition_can_be_harder_than_parsing), and to be found
in the [Grune-Jacobs book](http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition), relies on a very simple view of parsing as
an intersection of two languages: the first is the singleton regular
language containing the sentence $w$ to be parsed, and the second being
the language $L$ for which we are given a grammar $G$. The idea is
that a single sentence $w$ can always be read as a FSA (or a regular
grammar) as in the following example for the sentence $abac$
$$q_0 \stackrel{a}\longrightarrow q_1 \stackrel{b}\longrightarrow q_2
\stackrel{a}\longrightarrow q_3 \stackrel{c}\longrightarrow q_f$$

Using this FSA $A_w$ and the grammar $G$ of the language $L$ (assume
first $L$ to be a CF language, and $G$ a CFG), the old cross-product
construction due to [Bar-Hillel, Perles and Shamir (1961)](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25000219?uid=3738016&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104717280497) to prove
closure of CFL with regulr sets can be used with $A_w$ and $G$, and
yield a new CF grammar $G_w$, which naturally generates only $w$ when
$w\in L$, or the empty language $\emptyset$ when $w\notin L$. The
important point is that, when $w\in L$, the grammar $G_w$ generates
$w$ with exactly the same parse trees as the original grammar $G$, up
to a renaming of non-terminal, though the correspondence between
non-terminals is kept (let us ignore details). In other words, we just
described a parser that yield a parse forest $G_w$ from which all the
parse trees for $w$ can be extracted, simply by using the grammar
$G_w$ as a generator.

As it turns out, the dynamic programming chart parsers are just
optimized variants of this very basic construction called *parsing as
intersection*.

The nice point about it is that it lends itself to many variations.
Closure under intersection with regular languages is a very common
property, so that this is a guide for producing parsers for a great
variety of formalisms, though it makes effective sense only for those
that have a simple generating structure (loosely). Typically it works
very well for tree adjoining grammars (TAG) an other mildly context
sensitive languages.

Another point is that, rather than parse only strings, one can parse
complete regular sets, keeping only the sentences that are also in the
context-free language. And it is largely compatibles with the many
"optimization" techniques commonly found in chart parsing

This is very important in natural language processing (NLP), and
particularly in speech processing, since the result of the first pass
of speech processor to identify the spoken words is usually not a
single string of words, but what is usually called a word lattice
(see [Ambiguity and sharing in Natural Language Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903007/algorithms-or-data-structures-for-dealing-with-ambiguity/26132215#26132215), which is
actually the title of an answer to a question).

The interesting point is that a word lattice (see diagram in previous
reference) may be seen as a FSA that recognizes all the candidate
sentences (after noise processing) that could be the sentence to be
parsed. But chart parsing can be applied as well, as can the
intersection construction.

Now, it may well be that the word lattice contains spurious words to
be eliminated, or completely garbled sequences corresponding to
arbitrary number of missing words, or misunderstood words. That can be
modeled as a General Sequential Mapping (GSM) that does some editing
on the input sentence, adding, removing or substituting words,
possibly in a (finite) contextual way. Both regular and context free
languages are preserved by GSM mapping. Typically, the editing GSM can
be applied to the word lattice, yielding a new regual language and its
FSA (possibly even with cycles).  Then the parsing process is applied
to that new FSA.  This part is, I think, what you mainly wanted to
describe in the question.

The next point is that not all proposed sentences, or not all
corrections have the same likelyhood. Actually, word lattices may be
weighted structures that give weights to the corresponding sentences
in proportion to some likelyhood they they are correct.

Then the editing GSM can also have weighted transition corresponding
to some standard likelyhood that such error may have occurred.

Finally, the (CF) grammar of the language itself may be weighted.

The dynamic programming construction can use these weight (possibly
probabilities) to determine what are the most likely parses of the
given input according to the grammar used.

Note that I have been skipping the morphological analysis that
recognizes words, and uses similar techniques to end up with the word
lattice.

I am also skipping the use of attributes or feature structures, that
can combine with the process, provided they meet some algebraic
constraints.

The algebraic constraints (that concern also the numerical weights)
are related to the algebraic structures of the grammars themselves.
Typically, a CF derivation backbone (that is more than CF languages)
relies on [semiring structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).

A CF rule such as $X\to VXW | aV$ may be read as an equation of the
 form $X = V\cdot X\cdot W \cup \{a\}\cdot W$ where the wariables take
 their values in sets of sentences (i.e. in languages). The domain of
 languages is a semi-ring under the two operations: Union "$\cup$" and
 concatenation "$\cdot$". And a context-free grammar is a specific kind of equation in that domain.

You should find more on this use of semirings in Goodman's ["Parsing Inside-Out 1998.](http://arxiv.org/abs/cmp-lg/9805007)

There are some other references in [my answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/is-there-a-favoured-data-structure-for-storing-ambiguous-parse-trees-in-natural/6120#6120) to the question "[Is there a favoured data structure for storing ambiguous parse trees
in Natural Language Processing?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/is-there-a-favoured-data-structure-for-storing-ambiguous-parse-trees-in-natural)"

Comment: Great elaboration. One thing I didn't recognize is that the Earley parser is actually something with special characteristics. I always thought that it is just the other style of CYK. Instead of going bottom up, it goes top down.

Comment: Regarding Earley, I am no longer sure from memory. I will give a look at the parser to check, as there is a criterion for it (the shape of the forest). The criterion does not apply to CYK, as it is not a left-to-right parser. But Earley has another specificity, to compensate that it does not require the grammar to be made binary, which the algorithm does on the fly, with some consequences.  BTW, is that the kind of answer you wanted?

Comment: I was hoping to see what people have been doing, and you have lot of references in the answer. That is what I was hoping to see. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer is ok, upvoting is not forbidden ...:)